# Woo Commerce Settings for Check-out Form

Tags: admin, email, options

I am using Woo Commerce and am trying to change the settings that display the "Need Assistance? Call Customer service @ ....." and "Email then at ..." on the Checkout page: https://www.theresilientlife.org/checkout/

I've sent a ticket in to a "ninja" who responded:

"You're currently in the pre-sales department, and our Ninjas only offer assistance to paying customers under our Support Policy. WooCommerce is free and doesn't qualify.

Your options are:

```
Purchase one of our 300+ WooCommerce extensions to gain access to the Help Desk: http://www.woothemes.com/product-category/woocommerce-extensions/"
```

What??

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? I just want to change the contact phone # and email address that appears on the checkout form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to be a Woocommerce setting, or if it is in the Woocommerce settings, it has been added by an additional plugin from the theme maker.

> Check your theme settings, or for a widget that is configured to appear on user account pages.

Since the CSS style `.avada_myaccount_user` is being used for this header we can safely assume you are using the [Avada](http://theme-fusion.com/avada/) theme.

If nothing else, to disable it, you can always add

```
.avada_myaccount_user {
    display: none;
}
```

to your override.css file if it includes one, or look for this class in the stylesheet and add it.

**If you wish to request specific support, go back to the theme maker.**
Frankly, bothering the Automattic/Woothemes boys with such questions, I am surprised they were that kind with their answer. Woocommerce is an open source product and thus free to use, but if you want support you have to pay for it, or pay someone else who knows what they are doing.

Comment: Just a heads up... after seeing that you used Avaya template I checked your Google PageSpeed ranking https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theresilientlife.org%2F&tab=mobile
As expected, not pretty. If I were you I'd follow the suggestions Google provides.